# PowerShell and XAML data binding

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I'm trying to get a list of users searching by a surname property and list them in the ListView.

Here's XAML code:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
Title="Find users with SamAccountName"
Width="525"
Background="#FF262626"
ResizeMode="NoResize"
SizeToContent="Height">


<StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,5" Orientation="Vertical">


    <Grid
        Name="Grid"
        Width="400"
        Height="200"
        Background="#313130">
        <Label
            Name="Label"
            Content="Select employee"
            FontSize="12"
            Foreground="White" />
        <ListView
            Name="ListView"
            Margin="0,25,0,0"
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
            Foreground="White"
            IsHitTestVisible="False"
            SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn
                        Width="100"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Logon}"
                        Header="Logon" />
                    <GridViewColumn
                        Width="150"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"
                        Header="First name" />
                    <GridViewColumn
                        Width="150"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}"
                        Header="Last name" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Width="50" Content="SAVE" />
    </StackPanel>

</StackPanel>
```

And it looks like this:
[XAML look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxxvR.png)

I believe I cannot do it without data-binding and I saw a lot of posts about them but I couldn't understand it completely.

For now in powershell I have:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

$employees = Get-ADUser -Filter {Surname -like "surname"}

$itemSource = @()

ForEach ($employee in ($employees | Sort-Object SamAccountName)) {

$itemSource += [PSCustomObject]@ {

    Logon = $employee.Name
    FirstName = $employee.GivenName
    LastName = $employee.Surname

}

$columnOrder = 'Logon', 'FirstName', 'LastName'

[XML]$Form = Get-Content "xmlPath"

$NR = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $Form)
$Win = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($NR)

$Win.ShowDialog()
```

Now, the ForEach is working perfectly fine and returning exactly what I need but cannot find any way to put it into ViewList.

Then I'll need to save the selected user into a variable that I'll display later in the textbox.

Sorry if it's a stupid/easy question but I just started learning PowerShell to help me automate my work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the loaded form, you have to [specify the ListView's ItemsSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview#option-1-set-itemssource-in-c)

in PowerShell, you can do it like this

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
$employees = Get-ADUser -Filter {Surname -like "surname"}

$itemSource = @()

ForEach ($employee in $($employees | Sort-Object SamAccountName)) {

    $itemSource += [PSCustomObject]@{

        Logon = $employee.Name
        FirstName = $employee.GivenName
        LastName = $employee.Surname

    }
}
[XML]$Form = (Get-Content "C:\temp\test.xaml")
$NR = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $Form)
$Win = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($NR)
# this part
($win.FindName("ListView")).ItemsSource = $itemSource

$Win.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Sweet baby Jesus, that was SO easy.

Thank you so much!